# Detect what Button was clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to detect what Button was clicked, i use this Code but it does not move the Color from the first pressed Button to the second Pressed Button

```cs
public Form1()
{
          InitializeComponent();
          button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
          button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
          button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
          button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
          button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
}

private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         (sender as Button).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

What results in this, if multiple Buttons were Pressed:[image]

Comment: A `Button` has properties that will identify the button.

Comment: Yes you instructed it to do so. What do you need? to set the default backcolor on mouse up? then handle instead the mouse down (set red) and mouse up (reset to default).

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you're telling it to do, change the background color of the current control to red. You must first restore all buttons background colors to it's original and then set to red the one that raised the event.

Comment: We could go ahead and start giving out answers just to be the first ones to do so, but we still wouldn't know what problem you're trying to solve, or what final goal you're trying to achieve. As it is, your code does exactly as instructed. If it doesn't do what you expected it to, then what is it that you expect it to do EXACTLY?

Comment: @LucMorin I explained it well enough.

Comment: @Internal: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to reset the color of the buttons at the time of the click, so change it to something like this.

```
public Form1()
{
          InitializeComponent();
          button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
          button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
          button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
          button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
          button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
}

private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         //Resets button colors back to original. You will need to decide probably transparent I imagine though.
         button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
         button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
         button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
         button4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
         button5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
         //Sets the clicked button to red. 
         (sender as Button).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Then at the bottom you will change the button that is being clicked to Red.

This is a VERY VERY basic example of this and there are better ways, but it will achieve what you are wanting and hopefully explains it as well.